# Specify struct format in json.Marshal()

Tags: json, go, format, marshalling

I have the following structs, which I use to communicate with an API:

```
type Object struct {
    Id         uint64
    Type       string
    Class      string
    Properties []Property
}

type Property struct {
    Name     string
    DataType string
    Value    interface{}
}
```

And I use `json.MarshalIndent()` to convert my struct into a json before sending it. this gives me something like:

```
{
       "Id": 15,
       "Type": "Node",
       "Class": "Persona",
       "Properties": [
               {
                       "Name": "Nombre",
                       "DataType": "text",
                       "Value": "Oso"
               },
               {
                       "Name": "Edad",
                       "DataType": "int",
                       "Value": 45
               },
               {
                       "Name": "Fecha de Naciemiento",
                       "DataType": "date",
                       "Value": "1989-09-27T05:30:08-06:00"
               }
       ]
}
```

I want to format the `value` value (because it is of type `interface{}` I need to format it depending on the value type) of the struct Property before marshaling it.

The first solution that occurred to me was to create a `(Object) encode() string` function or something, that iterates through `[]Property` formatting the values, and marshaling each property separately, then reconstructing the Object with an `[]string` instead of the `[]Property` and then marshaling the object.

Is there any built-in way of doing this? If not, is there any idiomatic way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON encoder marshals interface{} values according to the actual type of the value. You can override the default encoding in a couple of ways.

The first is to create a wrapper around values to control how they are encoded using the  [Marshaler interface](http://godoc.org/encoding/json#Marshaler). Here's a wrapper that changes how integers are encoded:

```
type Value struct{ Value interface{} }

func (v Value) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
  switch v := v.Value.(type) {
  case int:
    return []byte(fmt.Sprintf("\"#%d\"", v)), nil
  default:
    return json.Marshal(v)
  }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
prop.Value = Value{45}
```

<kbd>[playground](http://play.golang.org/p/30T7LszaLg)</kbd>

A second approach is to implement the [Marshaler](http://godoc.org/encoding/json#Marshaler) on the Property type to override how all of the property is marshaled including the Value field.

```
func (p Property) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
  var buf bytes.Buffer
  buf.WriteString(`{"Name":`)
  d, err := json.Marshal(p.Name)
  if err != nil {
    return nil, err
  }
  buf.Write(d)
  buf.WriteString(`,"DataType":`)
  d, err = json.Marshal(p.DataType)
  if err != nil {
    return nil, err
  }
  buf.Write(d)
  buf.WriteString(`, "Value":`)
  switch v := p.Value.(type) {
  case int:
    fmt.Fprintf(&buf, "\"#%d\"", v)
  default:
    d, err := json.Marshal(v)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    buf.Write(d)
  }
  buf.WriteString("}")
  return buf.Bytes(), nil
}
```

<kbd>[playground](http://play.golang.org/p/uYj8-VDust)</kbd>

Comment: I know this. As you can see in my example. But I want to add some specific format to some types. Lets say I want dates to be in text format "Monday, March the first" or I want numbers to be shown as "#45".

Comment: I haven't see the update about implementing the Marshaler interface. Thats exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot